# How to display the related node content in a block?

Tags: views

How can I display the related content for a specific node (type product) in a block? I would like to display the image, title and a trimmed body of the related content (from the same company) at the end of the node.

Comment: you can use views arguments in views block to get the nodes info and then use filters to get the field output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Featured Content module](http://drupal.org/project/featured_content) for that.

Alternatively, you can also use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) by filtering your content using the node of the current page as an argument and using taxonomy or node reference to relate the content.